# How to rar the newest (The latest modified date file) file?

Tags: windows-server-2008, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I have the folder `c:\AA\` that everyday there will be a new BAK file.
When I run the command it will re-rar every files not just the newest file.

I use this batch code:

```
FOR %%A IN (C:\AA\*.txt*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" m "C:\AA\%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
```

Anyone know how I could zip file only the newest file?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `forfiles` command. Something like

```
FOR %%A IN ('FORFILES /D 0 /P c:\AA /M .txt') DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" m "C:\AA\%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
```